Order By Integer column, but based on custom priority
Given:
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE Result (
  ErrorCode INT
);

INSERT INTO Result(ErrorCode) VALUES (500);
INSERT INTO Result(ErrorCode) VALUES (-8000);
INSERT INTO Result(ErrorCode) VALUES (-7777);
INSERT INTO Result(ErrorCode) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO Result(ErrorCode) VALUES (1000);

I want to pull records order by the following priority:
1. -7777
2. Lowest negative to -1, incl.
3. Highest positive to 1, incl.
4. Zero
5. Anything else (although there shouldn't be)

i.e. that table should be sorted like this:
1. -7777
2. -8000
3. 1000
4. 500
5. 0

The closest I could get to is this:
SELECT *
FROM Result
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN ErrorCode = -7777 THEN 0
    WHEN ErrorCode < 0 THEN 1
    WHEN ErrorCode > 0 THEN 2
    WHEN ErrorCode = 0 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END) ASC;

Which gives me:
1. -7777
2. -8000 or any other negative number I may have in the table
3. 500 or 1000
4. 1000 or 500
5. 0

How do I modify my ORDER BY, to match my sorting criteria?

I would venture to ask what the use case is for this?

Figuring out the "worst" error code, where -7777 is the worst, then the lowest negative number is worst, then the highest positive and then 0 indicates no error. I know...

You don't have a tiebreaker. Both 500 and 1000 have a sort order of 2, and that's it, so they are ordered arbitrarily. Add another clause to make it deterministic.

Do you happen to have a table with all the error codes defined? You can then use a column to define the severity (unique INT) on each one, and use that for sorting.

@ThomA, I don't believe they're ordered "arbitrary", I think they follow the ASC ordering. Edit: never mind.

So is 2 before or after 2, @hyankov , and why is 2 always before/after 2? (Does your answer change if the value is 2 rather than `2? (Do you see the problem now?)

Actually now I see the problem with my statement. Well that makes my current problem even worse.

You can use a combination of CASE expressions and arithmetic operations to achieve the desired ordering.
Here's the modified query -
SELECT * FROM Result ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN ErrorCode = -7777 THEN 0
    WHEN ErrorCode < 0 THEN 1
    WHEN ErrorCode > 0 THEN 3 - (ErrorCode / (ErrorCode + 1))
    WHEN ErrorCode = 0 THEN 4
END, ErrorCode;


I appreciate the effort, unfortunately I don't think this works - https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=06d19661-42ce-4d69-ab73-bbbfe1c24ba1

"don't think this works" isn't a helpful statement, @hyankov . Explain why it doesn't work.

I have updated the query now please check

@ThomA it's pretty obvious, in the SQL Fiddle snippet I've included.

I clicked that, and I got a large banner about accept cookies or leave, which blocked view on the content behind, @hyankov , so I left. That, I'm afraid, left me none the wiser on why the answer here didn't work.

This shows a working version next to this (which still doesn't give the intended order) https://dbfiddle.uk/isKgKQ2T

ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN ErrorCode = -7777 THEN 0
    WHEN ErrorCode =     0 THEN 3
    WHEN ErrorCode <     0 THEN 1
    WHEN ErrorCode >     0 THEN 2
  END,
  ABS(ErrorCode) DESC

fiddle

Try it like here:
--    S Q L : 
Select   *
From     Result
Order By CASE 
              WHEN ErrorCode = -7777 THEN 0     --  -7777
              WHEN ErrorCode <= -1   THEN 10    --  Lowest negative to -1, incl.
              WHEN ErrorCode >=  1   THEN 20    --  Highest positive to 1, incl.
              WHEN ErrorCode =   0   THEN 30    --  Zero
          ELSE 99
          END, 
          Abs(ErrorCode) Desc  /* OR -> ErrorCode Desc <- depending on how you want to order negative numbers   */

/*    R e s u l t :
ErrorCode
---------
    -7777
    -8000
     1000
      500
        0      */

See the fiddle here.

Here's my attempt:
with cte as (
    select * from (values
        (500),
        (-8000),
        (-7777),
        (0),
        (1000)
    ) as x(ErrorCode)
)
select *
from cte
order by
    CASE
        WHEN ErrorCode = -7777 THEN 0
        WHEN ErrorCode <> 0    THEN 1
        WHEN ErrorCode = 0     THEN 2
    END,
    sign(ErrorCode),
    abs(ErrorCode) desc;

Exposition: I lifted your case statement in the order by but changed it so that values different from 0 (regardless of whether they're positive or negative) compare as equal. As to why that works, positive or negative numbers just need to sort ahead of zero at this stage. From there, I use the sign() function to determine if it's positive or negative, using the fact that it will return 1 or -1 (respectively) so that negative numbers will sort ahead of positive numbers. Then finally abs() to determine the magnitude of the number to break ties within the positive or negative classes.
